# Docker build output scripts ran from dockerfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm running a

```
docker build -t $NAME -f Dockerfile.test .
```

command.

In my `Dockerfile.test` I have at the end (I'm copying certain things to make everything work)

```
CMD["bin/bash", "-c", "bash /run-script.sh && bash /run-another-script.sh"]
```

When I look at my build stages in Jenkins, I can only see that everything passed ok, the

```
CMD /bin/bash -c bash /run-script.sh && bash /run-another-script.sh
```

was executed, and since I'm running a sonarqube scan in these scripts, I can see in my sonarqube that a scan happened (which is ok).

But since I'm running PHP unit tests in the scripts, I'm a bit suspicious that this part, because in the Jenkins this was done very quickly (on my local computer running unit testing with coverage report takes ~20min), failed, or didn't run as it should.

So I'd like to see the output of these scripts (`run-script.sh` and `run-another-script.sh`) to be sure that everything works as intended.

I've heard that docker won't show the output of the scripts that write/delete lines in the terminal, so this might be the reason (I'm guessing ofc).

Is there a way to show the output?

Comment: Just to be sure. Are you actually launching your image on jenkins after the build? `CMD` is the command to be run, when you do `docker run image:tag`. During `docker build` the command is only stored in the meta-information of the image. If you want to run your script at build-time you'd need to use `RUN ...` not `CMD ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing `RUN` and `CMD`.

`RUN`-commands are executed during the build (`docker build`), `CMD`-commands are executed when you start the container (`docker run`).

To be certain I have written a small test:

1. Using CMD

   $ docker build -t cmdtest -<<EOF
   FROM centos:7

   RUN echo "echo script1" > script1.sh
   RUN echo "echo script2" > script2.sh

   CMD ["bin/bash", "-c", "bash /script1.sh && bash /script2.sh"]
   EOF

does not print anything, because not executed. However, prints at `docker run`:

```
$ docker run cmdtest
> script1
> script2
```

2. Using RUN

   $ docker build -t cmdtest -<<EOF
   FROM centos:7

   RUN echo "echo script1" > script1.sh
   RUN echo "echo script2" > script2.sh

   RUN ["bin/bash", "-c", "bash /script1.sh && bash /script2.sh"]
   EOF

   > Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
   > ...
   > Step 4/4 : RUN bin/bash -c bash /script1.sh && bash /script2.sh
   > ---> Running in 7aab2725ed25
   >
   > script1
   > script2
   > ---> 8ca71d1c67e8

prints at build-time.

Comment: Hmm this might actually be what I need, as I doubt that my test stage will be run. Will test  it out tomorrow. Do I need to somehow 'end' the Dockerfile, or can the last command be `RUN`?

Comment: No, there's no need to 'end' the Dockerfile. It can look just as my examples (without the EOF stuff)